# How can I detect if a given URL is the current one?

Tags: php, regex, url

I need to detect if a provided URL matches the one currently navigated to. Mind you the following are all valid, yet semantically equivalent URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/page/index.php?parameter=value
https://www.example.com/path/to/page/index.php
https://www.example.com/path/to/page/
https://www.example.com/path/to/page
http://www.example.com/path/to/page
//www.example.com/path/to/page
//www/path/to/page
../../../path/to/page
../../to/page
../page
./
```

The final function **must** return `true` if the given URL points back to the current page, or `false` if it does not. **I do not have a list of expected URLs**; this will be used for a client who just wants links to be disabled when they link to the current page. **Note that I wish to ignore parameters**, as these do not indicate the current page on this site. I got as far as using the following regex:

```
/^((https?:)?\/\/www(\.example\.com)\/path\/to\/page\/?(index.php)?(\?.+=.*(\&.+=.*)*)?)|(\.\/)$/i
```

where `https?`, `www`, `\.example\.com`, `\/path\/to\/page`, and `index.php` are dynamically detected with `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` and made into regex form, but that doesn't match the relative URLs like `../../to/page`.

**EDIT:** I got a bit farther with the regex: [refiddle.co/gv8](http://refiddle.co/gv8)
now I'd just need PHP to dynamically create the regex for any given page.

Comment: how about `if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $array))`

Comment: Can you not just use `strpos()` after normalising the input (strip end params and beginning `http://(www.)?` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany can you please elaborate on your solution in a full answer?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP can you please elaborate on your solution in a full answer?

Comment: I have a feeling this is an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is ultimate goal that is requiring you to attempt this? Adding an active state to a nav item?

Comment: @Supruhstar can you please do at least a little of the coding and thinking yourself..

Comment: @SmokeyPHP The ultimate goal is to have an item that will link out if and only if it does not link back to this page (similar to what Wikipedia `[[links]]` do.)

Comment: @DanFromGermany I did plenty already, but this is where I'm stuck. Your approach assumes I have some sort of array, but I never said I do.

Comment: @Supuhstar: regarding the edit: `I'd just need PHP to dynamically create the regex for any given page` -- please post that as a new question.

Comment: Check [this](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/05/php_tip_how_convert_relative_url_absolute_url) out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have been paid to work on this for the last couple days, I wasn't just sitting around waiting for an answer. I've come up with one that works in my test platform; what does everyone else think? It feels a little bloated, but also feels bulletproof.

Debug echoes left in in case you wanna echo out some stuffs.

```
global $debug;$debug = false; // toggle debug echoes and var_dumps


/**
 * Returns a boolean indicating whether the given URL is the current one.
 * 
 * @param $otherURL the other URL, as a string. Can be any URL, relative or canonical. Invalid URLs will not match.
 * 
 * @return true iff the given URL points to the same place as the current one
 */
function isCurrentURL($otherURL)
{global $debug;
    if($debug)echo"<!--\r\nisCurrentURL($otherURL)\r\n{\r\n";

    if ($thisURL == $otherURL) // unlikely, but possible. Might as well check.
        return true;

    // BEGIN Parse other URL
    $otherProtocol = parse_url($otherURL);
    $otherHost = $otherProtocol["host"] or null; // if $otherProtocol["host"] is set and is not null, use it. Else, use null.
    $otherDomain = explode(".", $otherHost) or $otherDomain;
    $otherSubdomain = array_shift($otherDomain); // subdom only
    $otherDomain = implode(".", $otherDomain); // domain only
    $otherFilepath = $otherProtocol["path"] or null;
    $otherProtocol = $otherProtocol["scheme"] or null;
    // END Parse other URL

    // BEGIN Get current URL
    #if($debug){echo '$_SERVER == '; var_dump($_SERVER);}
    $thisProtocol = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]; // http or https
    $thisHost = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; // subdom or subdom.domain.tld
    $thisDomain = explode(".", $thisHost);
    $thisSubdomain = array_shift($thisDomain); // subdom only
    $thisDomain = implode(".", $thisDomain); // domain only
    if ($thisDomain == "")
        $thisDomain = $otherDomain;
    $thisFilepath = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; // /path/to/file.php
    $thisURL = "$thisProtocol://$thisHost$thisFilepath";
    // END Get current URL

    if($debug)echo"Current URL is $thisURL ($thisProtocol, $thisSubdomain, $thisDomain, $thisFilepath).\r\n";
    if($debug)echo"Other URL is $otherURL ($otherProtocol, $otherHost, $otherFilepath).\r\n";

    $thisDomainRegexed = isset($thisDomain) && $thisDomain != null && $thisDomain != "" ? "(\." . str_replace(".","\.",$thisDomain) . ")?" : ""; // prepare domain for insertion into regex
    //                                                                                                      v this makes the last slash before index.php optional
    $regex = "/^(($thisProtocol:)?\/\/$thisSubdomain$thisDomainRegexed)?" . preg_replace('/index\\\..+$/i','?(index\..+)?', str_replace(array(".", "/"), array("\.", "\/"), $thisFilepath)) . '$/i';

    if($debug)echo "\r\nregex is $regex\r\nComparing regex against $otherURL";
    if (preg_match($regex, $otherURL))
    {
        if($debug)echo"\r\n\tIt's a match! Returning true...\r\n}\r\n-->";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if($debug)echo"\r\n\tOther URL is NOT a fully-qualified URL in this subdomain. Checking if it is relative...";
        if($otherURL == $thisFilepath) // somewhat likely
        {
            if($debug)echo"\r\n\t\tOhter URL and this filepath are an exact match! Returning true...\r\n}\r\n-->";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if($debug)echo"\r\n\t\tFilepath is not an exact match. Testing against regex...";
            $regex = regexFilepath($thisFilepath);
            if($debug)echo"\r\n\t\tNew Regex is $regex";
            if($debug)echo"\r\n\t\tComparing regex against $otherFilepath...";
            if (preg_match($regex, $otherFilepath))
            {
                if($debug)echo"\r\n\t\t\tIt's a match! Returning true...\r\n}\r\n-->";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if($debug)echo"\r\nI tried my hardest, but couldn't match $otherURL to $thisURL. Returning false...\r\n}\r\n-->";
    return false;
}

/**
 * Uses the given filepath to create a regex that will match it in any of its relative representations.
 * 
 * @param $path the filepath to be converted
 * 
 * @return a regex that matches a all relative forms of the given filepath
 */
function regexFilepath($path)
{global $debug;
    if($debug)echo"\r\nregexFilepath($path)\r\n{\r\n";

    $filepathArray = explode("/", $path);
    if (count($filepathArray) == 0)
        throw new Exception("given parameter not a filepath: $path");
    if ($filepathArray[0] == "") // this can happen if the path starts with a "/"
        array_shift($filepathArray); // strip the first element off the array
    $isIndex = preg_match("/^index\..+$/i", end($filepathArray));
    $filename = array_pop($filepathArray);

    if($debug){var_dump($filepathArray);}

$ret = '';
foreach($filepathArray as $i)
    $ret = "(\.\.\/$ret$i\/)?"; // make a pseudo-recursive relative filepath
if($debug)echo "\r\n$ret";
$ret = preg_replace('/\)\?$/', '?)', $ret); // remove the last '?' and add one before the last '\/'
if($debug)echo "\r\n$ret";
$ret = '/^' . ($ret == '' ? '\.\/' : "((\.\/)|$ret)") . ($isIndex ? '(index\..+)?' : str_replace('.', '\.', $filename)) . '$/i'; // if this filepath leads to an index.php (etc.), then that filename is implied and irrelevant.

if($debug)echo'\r\n}\r\n';
}
```

This seems to match everything I need it to match, and not what I don't need it to.

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is no way to predict the total list of valid URLs that will result in display of the current page, since you can't predict (or control) external links that might link back to the page.  What if someone uses TinyURL or bit.ly?  A regex will not cut the mustard.

If what you need is to insure that a link does not result in the same page, then you need to TEST it.  Here's a basic concept:

1. Every page has a unique ID.  Call it a serial number.  It should be persistent.  The serial number should be embedded somewhere predictable (though perhaps invisibly) within the page.
2. As the page is created, your PHP will need to walk through all the links for each page, visit each one, and determine whether the link resolves to a page with a serial number that matches the calling page's serial number.
3. If the serial number does not match, display the link as a link.  Otherwise, display something else.

Obviously, this will be an arduous, resource-intensive process for page production.  You really don't want to solve your problem this way.

With your "ultimate goal" comment in mind, I suspect your best approach is to be approximate.  Here are some strategies...

**First** option is also the simplest. If you're building a content management system that USUALLY creates links in one format, just support that format.  Wikipedia's approach works because a `[[link]]` is something THEY generate, so THEY know how it's formatted.

**Second** is more the direction you've gone with your question.  The elements of a URL are "protocol", "host", "path" and "query string".  You can break them out into a regex, and *possibly* get it right.  You've already stated that you intend to ignore the query string.  So ... start with `'((https?:)?//(www\.)?example\.com)?' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and add endings to suit.  Other answers are already helping you with this.

**Third** option is quite a bit more complex, but gives you more fine-grained control over your test.  As with the last option, you have the various URL elements.  You can test for the validity of each *without* using a regex.  For example:

```php
$a = array();                                 // init array for valid URLs

// Step through each variation of our path...
foreach([$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']] as $path) {

  // Step through each variation of our host...
  foreach ([$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0]] as $server) {
    // Step through each variation of our protocol...
    foreach (['https://','http://','//'] as $protocol) {
      // Set the URL as a key.
      $a[ $protocol . $server . $path ] = 1;
    }
  }

  // Also for each path, step through directories and parents...
  $apath=explode('/', $path);                 // turn the path into an array
  unset($apath[0]);                           // strip the leading slash
  for( $i = 1; $i <= count($apath); $i++ ) {
    if (strlen($apath[$i])) {
      $a[ str_repeat("../", 1+count($apath)-$i) . implode("/", $apath) ] = 1;
                                              // add relative paths
    }
    unset($apath[$i]);
  }

  $a[ "./" . implode("/", $apath) ] = 1;      // add current directory

}
```

Then simply test whether the link (minus its query string) is an index within the array.  Or adjust to suit; I'm sure you get the idea.

I like this third solution the best.

Answer (score 0):

A regex isn't actually necessary to strip off all the query parameters. You could use [`strok()`](http://php.net/strok):

```
$url = strtok($url, '?');
```

And, to check the output for your URL array:

```
$url_list = <<<URL
https://www.example.com/path/to/page/index.php?parameter=value
https://www.example.com/path/to/page/index.php    
...    
./?parameter=value
./
URL;

$urls = explode("\n", $url_list);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $url = strtok($url, '?'); // remove everything after ?
    echo $url."\n";
}
```

As a function (could be improved):

```
function checkURLMatch($url, $url_array) {
    $url = strtok($url, '?'); // remove everything after ?
    if( in_array($url, $url_array)) {
        // url exists array
        return True;
    } else {
        // url not in array
        return False;
    }
}
```

[**See it live!**](http://codepad.org/y3VWECdq)

Comment: Is this guaranteed to NOT match a URL such as, say `http://www.example.com/path/to/else` or `../`? Getting it to match is easy, but I need to guarantee I don't get false positives here.
Mind you, this will NOT have enumerated URLs as listed above; this will be for a generic-use library.

Comment: @Supuhstar: I believe it should work for all the test cases you mentioned above. You can conduct further tests to make sure it's *exactly* what you want. My answer might help as a starting point. Also, I'm aware this is for a different use-case, but I just wanted to include the tests, too. :-)

Comment: In the final test, there will be no array of matching URLs. The ones in my question are just ones I thought of to remind readers how many variations of a URL mean the same thing.

Comment: @Supuhstar: As I said before, it's just to demonstrate the function. So, does this answer not help?

Comment: @AmalMurani It doesn't, because it relies on a premade array of URLs, and no such array will be available in the wild

Comment: @Supuhstar: Ah, you're right. I just saw your answer and now understand what you *were* trying to do. The question wasn't very clear on this, TBH. Anyway, I assume the issue has been resolved. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
function checkURL($me, $s) {
   $dir = dirname($me) . '/';
   // you may need to refine this
   $s = preg_filter(array('~^//~', '~/$~', '~\?.*$~', '~\.\./~'),
                    array('', '', '', $dir), $s);
   // parse resulting URL
   $url = parse_url($s);
   var_dump($url);
   // match parsed URL's path with self
   return ($url['path'] === $me);
}

// your page's URL with stripped out .php    
$me = str_replace('.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// assume this is the URL you are matching against
$s = '../page/';

// compare $me with $s
$ret = checkURL($me, $s);

var_dump($ret);
```

**Live Demo: http://ideone.com/OZZM53**

Comment: I can't get this to ever return true.

Comment: I posted this after testing only. Which URL from your list you used for testing?

Comment: literally all are used for testing. here's my test page, slightly modified for sharing: http://refiddle.com/gv8

Comment: Hmm that fiddle is matching URLs by pure regex. My solution was little different actually if you notice. Let me see if I can build a demo for you.

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing... could you write it as a function that takes in one URL and gives out a boolean?

Comment: Why do you strip the `.php`? `http://example.com/file.php` isn't the same as `http://example.com/file/`

Comment: Because none of the URLs you're trying to match are showing `.php` extension and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` might give you string with `.php` in the end.

Comment: Look again; they all point to `/index.php`. If you strip `.php` from `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, then it will point to `/index/index.php`.